# Out-file elevated Credentials Error: The Device is not Ready

Tags: powershell, logging, credentials

I have a PowerShell Application that has a gui user interface and my goal is to log the activity of all users I release the application to, in one central location.

Also, this has to be secure, so something like "Give everyone write access to the log file" would not be an acceptable solution.

I believe I have successfully accomplished running powershell as another user, but my function breaks when it tries to run out-file or >> commands.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
function Start-ElevatedCode
{
    param([ScriptBlock]$Code)
    Start-Process -Credential $logCred -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -WorkingDirectory \\Server\d$ -ArgumentList $code
    Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe -Credential $logCred
    Start-Process $PSHOME\powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command `"&{`"`this is output string`' >> `'D:\Pojo Super User\Change.txt`'`"}`"" -Wait
}
```

Obviously I do not need all three of these, but just the one I can get to work. The first line is what I really need to work, the other two are just for testing/example.
Output of these three commands respectively:
`Out-file : The device is not ready.`

`Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: The directory name is invalid.`

`The device is not ready.`

The $code var I am passing in is:
 `$code = {$logString | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\LogPath\Change.txt'}`

Powershell V2 and below and cmd commands only please. This must work across all systems.

Anyone have an idea of why this generic system error message is being generated?
 cmd `net helpmsg 21`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have came up with a solution, and am posting to show what I am trying to achieve:
Now I am directly remoting into the server and executing the command.

```
Function ActivityLog {
param ($logEntry)
    $sesh = New-PSSession -ComputerName theserver -Credential $logCred
    invoke-command -Session $sesh {param($str) $str | out-file 'D:\myApplication\Activity.log' -Append} -Args $logEntry 
    Remove-PSSession -Session $sesh
}
$string = "$date : User $user Restarted application with commandLine : $cmd and PID: $pid"
ActivityLog $string
```

Although this function works as intended, it should not take 1/2 of a second to write a String to a text file. 
I will leave this question open for a few days, in hopes that someone has a solution with better efficiency. (One that does not require a remote connection)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to centralize logging, use [`Write-EventLog`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849847.aspx) and collect the events via [event forwarding](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748890.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, This solution unfortunately wouldn't work for me, I dont think. Although I know that this application will only be run within the network, I do not personally have admin privileges on all the computers that it could be run on.

Comment: Then I suggest you either contact the people who have, or give up on the idea of centralized logging. How do you think you'll handle concurrent write access to your file?

Comment: Prevention: It is really just a simple process manager application, except tuned to monitor our java.exe processes(and relate corresponding application to process). Before any Activity.log entry, a process is killed. So if 2 users try to kill the same application at the same time, one will throw an error. The one that errors doesn't get logged. Sounds easy enough to me, although I can't say I have thoroughly tested this.